# How do I make an html table like that?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to make an html table with two columns and three rows but should look like [that](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s238/sh/4f532e1d-4dbf-4a0e-ac2c-877a6d2d69df/828b9489c8cd4f32224351b70344397c).

I tried different ways with colspan and rowspan but can't make it seem like the way i want. I got frustrated and thats why I ask if someone can help me with that.

Million thanks for helping...

Comment: How do know it's a table and not CSS?

Comment: ohh, you are right...

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element) awesome article will help you.

Comment: Doesn't really look like `tabular` data, so I'm not sure I would mark it up as a `<table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't consider `<table>` element to do a web layout. By the way, this could be easily done with clean and valid html structure + css.

A working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ALRpn/

Be sure to only use tables for tabular data.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `<blockquote>` and `<cite>` too :)

Comment: Sure, but at least, if he uses div instead of table, it's ok for me :) Feel free to edit the fiddle. Could be great to use <figure> too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rudimentary "table" with CSS.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/NzkRf/)

HTML

```
<div class='leftholder'>
   <div class='leftupper'></div>
   <div class='leftlower'></div>
</div>

<div class='rightholder'>
    <div class='right1'></div>
    <div class='right2'></div>
    <div class='right3'></div>
</div>
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it.